# Exclude entire blob from a grep pipe

Tags: bash, grep

So I have a few log files which contain a bunch of exception stack traces. What I am trying to do is to get a stack trace if a particular Exception message is present and then exclude that entire blob if a particular method signature is present in the blob, and finally write to a file.

So to give an example,

```
zgrep -A 65 "Exception Message to Grep For" FileNamePrefix* | grep -v "exclude function name" > storage_file.txt
```

What ends up happening is, grep searches for the "Exception Message to Grep For" and gets a blob of lines, but the second grep just removes the one line which is "exclude function name", and saves the rest of the blob to the storage file.

What I am trying to do is to ignore the entire blob in the second grep, if the "exclude function name" text is present in the blob.

Is there a good way to achieve this with grep?

Comment: Are you trying to find files that contain one string but not another? What does "blob" mean in this context?

Comment: "Are you trying to find files that contain one string but not another?" - No. I am trying to filer my grep search from my first grep (which contains about 65 lines) based on a keyword I want to exclude. 

To put it simply, I am searching for exception stack traces (first grep), which can be caused due to multiple methods, and excluding the stack trace that contains a specific method  name. (second grep)

" What does "blob" mean in this context?" - So a blob would be the output of the first grep, i.e the 65 lines (-A 65) that contains the search keyword which is used in the first grep.

Comment: an you include a shortened version of a loh with a blob and what should remain? I am think your blob starts with a left-aligned line, possible including a date, and the blob is indented with at least one space and runs until the next line with a date (or EOF). When you show what to look for, it is easier to make a script. Or are you sure each blob has the search string on the first line and exactly 64 lines blob after this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
 awk '
   BEGIN{x=-1;b=""};
   /Exception Message to Grep For/{x=NR+65};
   (x!=-1){b=b$0"\n"};
   /exclude function name/{x=-1;b=""};
   (x==NR){print b"----";b=""};
   END{if(x!=-1){print b"----"}};' filename.txt
```

Comment: In the first and second last line, couldn't you write `x=-1` instead? That way you wouldn't have the 100000 lines limitation.

Comment: I think there are some small bugs in here. **(1.)** If any near-last line matches `/Exception.../` it won't be printed since `NR+65` is higher than the total number of lines in the file. **(2.)** If two lines that match `/Exception.../` are close to each other the first won't be printed as at the second match `b` is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep` you can treat the *blobs* (created by `-A 65`) as a single line using the `-z` option. Replace the blob-delimiters `--` with the null byte, then filter the null-delimited blobs, and change the null-delimiters back to `--`.

```
zgrep -A 65 'Exception Message' FileNamePrefix* |
sed 's/^--$/\x00/' |
grep -zv 'exclude function name' |
sed '$s/\x00//;s/\x00/--/'
```

This command assumes that the blobs do not contain the line `--` themselves. Lines containing `--` **and** something different are fine though. For instance, `---` would be fine. Since you are using `grep` on (I assume) *multiple* files starting with `FileNamePrefix` each line will be prefixed with a `FileNamePrefix…` and therefore the command is safe.